# Why doesn't AIR start full size?

Tags: flash, flex3, air

I have an AIR application set to 800px wide and 600px high. When I launch it, the window starts too small with horizontal and vertical scrollbars? Isn't this dumb? What am I missing?

Test.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="800" height="600">

</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a new project, that code works fine.
Check in your {app-name}.app.xml file and check the settings there, particularly 'maxSize'.
This won't be set by default, but could have been set by you or someone you got that project from.